# AWS issues: launch a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services

This question was copied from an earlier post, although as I have not the reputation count to answer it; I've chosen to pose it again here;

I'm trying to launch a docker container, as job into an ec2 instance.

The EC2 instance is launched using the aws cli and UserData Shell Script encoded in base64:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=<TEMPLATE_ID>,Version=19 --key-name <KEY_NAME> --region <REGION> --user-data "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"
```

The base64 decoded script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wait for specific service to be ready
while ! curl -sSf http://OTHER_AWS_IP:80/ping &> /dev/null; do
        echo "Waiting for HTTP server to be ready..."
        sleep 5
done
docker run --net smsnet -p 80:8090 -e UPLOAD_FOLDER=/app/upload/ -e PIPELINE_FOLDER=/app/pipeline/ -e spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://OTHER_AWS_IP:3306/ -e spring.datasource.username=DB_USER -e spring.datasource.password=DB_PASS -e spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver -e MYSQL_ADDR=OTHER_AWS_IP:3306 -e ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=AWS -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY> -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<AWS_DEFAULT_REGION> -e AWS_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=<TEMPLATE_ID>,Version=19 -e AWS_LAN_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> -e AWS_PUBLIC_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> -e API_VERSION=V0.0.1 -e AWS_S3_BUCKET=<AWS_S3_BUCKETID> api:V0.0.1 java -jar /app/pipeline/lpp.jar /app/upload/1000040/1/config.txt
sudo poweroff -f now
```

The instance starts but the UserData Script is not launched.

Searching into the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

2024-02-07 14:56:44,040 - init.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'b'"IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKIyBXYWl'...'

Instead if I use a simple script like:

`echo "test" > /home/ec2-user/test.txt`

I will find the test.txt

I also tried to decode the original script into the new instance and launch manually using

```
echo "BASE64encodedscripthere" | base64 --decode > script.sh
sh script.sh
```

The script is executed without any errors.

What am I doing wrong ?

The problem was broken down into segments;

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wait for a specific service to be ready
while ! curl -sSf http://OTHER_AWS_IP:80/ping &> /dev/null; do
    echo "Waiting for the HTTP server to be ready..."
    sleep 5
done

# Run the Docker container
docker run --net smsnet -p 80:8090 \
    -e UPLOAD_FOLDER=/app/upload/ \
    -e PIPELINE_FOLDER=/app/pipeline/ \
    -e spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://OTHER_AWS_IP:3306/ \
    -e spring.datasource.username=DB_USER \
    -e spring.datasource.password=DB_PASS \
    -e spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver \
    -e MYSQL_ADDR=OTHER_AWS_IP:3306 \
    -e ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=AWS \
    -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY> \
    -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> \
    -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<AWS_DEFAULT_REGION> \
    -e AWS_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=<TEMPLATE_ID>,Version=19 \
    -e AWS_LAN_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> \
    -e AWS_PUBLIC_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> \
    -e API_VERSION=V0.0.1 \
    -e AWS_S3_BUCKET=<AWS_S3_BUCKETID> \
    api:V0.0.1 java -jar /app/pipeline/lpp.jar /app/upload/1000040/1/config.txt

# Shut down the instance
sudo poweroff -f now
```

Here are some steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Check Cloud-Init Logs:
The error message you received indicates that the UserData script was not handled correctly. Check the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log file on your EC2 instance for more details. It might provide insights into why the script isn’t executing as expected1.

Verify Permissions and Dependencies:

Ensure that the Docker daemon is running on your EC2 instance.

Confirm that the necessary permissions are set for Docker and other resources (e.g., AWS S3 bucket, RDS database).

Verify that the required dependencies (e.g., Java, MySQL) are installed and accessible.

Test a Simplified Script:
As a test, try a simplified UserData script that runs a basic Docker container. For example:
#!/bin/bash
docker run -p 80:3000 -d 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest
Replace the image name and port as needed. If this works, gradually add back the other environment variables and configurations.
Debugging Tips:
Use echo statements within your UserData script to log messages to the console. This can help you identify where the script might be failing.
Check the Docker logs (docker logs <container_id>) for any errors related to your container.
Remember to replace placeholders like <OTHER_AWS_IP>, <AWS_ACCESS_KEY>, <AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>, <AWS_DEFAULT_REGION>, <TEMPLATE_ID>, and <AWS_S3_BUCKETID> with actual values specific to your setup.

For the base64 decoded script;

1. Cloud-Init Logs:
   The warning message in the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log indicates that the UserData script was not handled correctly. Let’s investigate further.
   Check if there are any additional logs or error messages in the same log file. Look for any clues about why the script isn’t running as intended.
   Base64 Decoding and Execution:
   You mentioned that manually decoding and executing the script works without errors. This suggests that the script itself is correct.
   However, when launched as UserData, it doesn’t behave as expected. This points to an issue related to the environment or execution context.
   Environment and Dependencies:
   Ensure that the necessary dependencies (such as Docker) are installed on your EC2 instance.
2. Verify that the Docker daemon is running (systemctl status docker) and that the Docker image (api:V0.0.1) is available.
   Confirm that the EC2 instance has internet connectivity to pull the Docker image.
   Debugging Tips:
   Add debugging statements to your UserData script to log messages. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting UserData script..."
```

## Rest of your script

Check the Docker logs (docker logs <container_id>) for any errors related to your container.
Consider using absolute paths for Docker commands and other resources (e.g., /usr/bin/docker instead of docker).
User Data Execution Order:
User Data scripts run during instance initialization. Ensure that the Docker service is fully started before attempting to run containers.
You might need to add a delay or loop to wait for Docker to be ready before executing the docker run command.
Security Groups and Network Configuration:
Confirm that your EC2 instance’s security group allows outbound traffic to access the Docker registry (if pulling images from an external registry).
Verify that the EC2 instance has the necessary network configuration (e.g., correct subnet, route table, internet gateway).

3. Environment and Dependencies:
   Ensure that the necessary dependencies (such as Docker) are installed on your EC2 instance.
   Verify that the Docker daemon is running (systemctl status docker) and that the Docker image (api:V0.0.1) is available. Confirm that the EC2 instance has internet connectivity to pull the Docker image.
4. Debugging Tips:

Add debugging statements to your UserData script to log messages. For example:

#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting UserData script..."

## Rest of your script

Check the Docker logs (docker logs <container_id>) for any errors related to your container.
Consider using absolute paths for Docker commands and other resources (e.g., /usr/bin/docker instead of docker).

5. User Data Execution Order:
   User Data scripts run during instance initialization. Ensure that the Docker service is fully started before attempting to run containers.
   You might need to add a delay or loop to wait for Docker to be ready before executing the docker run command.
6. Security Groups and Network Configuration:
   Confirm that your EC2 instance’s security group allows outbound traffic to access the Docker registry (if pulling images from an external registry).
   Verify that the EC2 instance has the necessary network configuration (e.g., correct subnet, route table, internet gateway).
7. Test a Simplified Script:
   As a test, try a simplified UserData script that runs a basic Docker container (similar to your successful manual test). If this works, gradually reintroduce the other environment variables and configurations.

Remember to replace placeholders like <OTHER_AWS_IP>, <AWS_ACCESS_KEY>, <AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>, <AWS_DEFAULT_REGION>, <TEMPLATE_ID>, and <AWS_S3_BUCKETID> with actual values specific to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

> To specify user data when you launch your instance, use the run-instances command with the `--user-data` parameter. With `run-instances`, the AWS CLI performs base64 encoding of the user data for you.

You don't need to encode your script when you're running the instance from AWS CLI. Just pass it inline or from a file:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data file://my-script.sh
```